# Using special characters in Apache mod rewrite rule

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

We're trying to clean up some 404's on our site and some website is linking to /page.html%C2%A0. I'm trying to match the url with mod rewrite and redirect it to /page.html

```
RewriteRule ^page.html%C2%A0 /page.html [R=301,L]
```

This doesn't seem to match the url, I've also tried escaping the percent signs to \%, but that doesn't match either.

Anyone know how to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at your example, I think the problem is likely that you didn't include the leading `/` that's part of the request.  The [apache mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#quoting) do say that a \ should work. Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/page.html%C2%A0 /page.html [R=301,L]
```

Or:

```
RewriteRule ^/page.html\%C2\%A0 /page.html [R=301,L]
```

If none of those work for some reason, you could always try hitting it with a bigger hammer (a more inclusive ruleset that avoids using the special characters explicitely):

```
RewriteRule ^/?page.html.+ /page.html [R=301,L]
```

That will redirect `page.html` (with or without a leading `/`) followed by one or more of any character to just straight `/page.html`.

Comment: I ended up hitting it with the biggest hammer to get it working and use the ^page.html.+ regex. Thanks.